# Addition over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I'm looking at $\mathbb{F}_4 = \{0,1,\omega,\omega^2\}$ and wondering how to do addition in this field.

I have three expressions: $16$, $4\omega + 4\omega^2$, $6 + 5\omega + 5\omega^2$

I understand how to do addition over $\mathbb{Z}_4$, since it's just modular arithmetic, but I believe it is not the same over $\mathbb{F}.$

Comment: I haven't studied ring theory, so I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: You have the rules $1+1=0$, $\omega+\omega=0$, $\omega^2=\omega+1$. Everything follows from those.

Comment: Then, the answers are just: $0, 0, 1$, respectively?

Comment: "The underlying ring is Z2×Z2" — this is not even wrong. Additive group of this field is $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z ^2$, but direct product of nontrivial rings has evident zero divisors and therefore is not a field.
Speaking of a problem: this is modular arithmetic, but not over $\mathbb Z$: actually, every finite field of char = 2 is isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z [x]$ by certain polynomial. For your case, you can take polynomials modulo $x^2 + 1$ (prove that this ring is a field).

Comment: @xsnl Of course I meant "underlying additive group". In any case $x^2 + 1$ factors in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ as $(x + 1)^2$, so the image of $x + 1$ under the projection $\Bbb Z_2[x] \to \Bbb Z_2[x] / (x^2 + 1)$ is a zero divisor in the quotient ring, and hence that quotient is not a field. In this case we essentially have only one option, as the only irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: That's correct, Arsalan Dashti. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In this field, we have $0 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = (1 + 1) (1 + 1)$, so we must have $1 + 1 = 0$. For the same reason, $\omega + \omega = 0$ (and $\omega^2 + \omega^2 = 0$).

Among the remaining sums to determine is $1 + \omega$. Can this sum be any of $0, 1, \omega$?